# Looking for free / open source Lidar web viewer?

Tags: openlayers-2, postgis, open-source-gis, lidar, software-recommendations

I have lidar data which I want deploy my users using web viewer.

I will probably hold the data in PostGIS (not sure yet).

Is there good open source/free lidar viewer that I can integrate with OpenLayers site?

Comment: What's the problem with OpenLayers itself?

Comment: Lidar should be 3D viewer , with abilities like slicing , dots intensity... Openlayers doesn't support that (as much as I know)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an Open Source project especially to read and write LiDAR (and any other source of pointcloud data) format. This library, called PDAL is located at http://www.pointcloud.org/

I've seen demo using OpenLayers reading data from a PDAL source, but can't locate it anymore. Your best bet would be to ask on the mailing-list over there.

**Edit**

Boundless just updated their Lidar Tutorial that does use OpenLayers :
http://workshops.boundlessgeo.com/tutorial-lidar/

Comment: I need basic capabilites for the lidar.. like slicing...
Will it support it ?

Comment: I'm fairly sure it does support slicing, but you will have to ask over there to make sure. It supports all the basic capabilities. Mailing-list available at: http://www.pointcloud.org/community.html#mailing-lists